# specify exact plot location on letter size paper

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I am using R and I am trying to create a plot with elements that are at exactly locations on an 8.5x11 page. For example, I need a point at .25 inches from the left of the page and .75 inches from the top of the page. When I save the plot to a pdf, the point is close, but not quite where it should be. What setting in par() do I need to adjust to get the points and lines in the right, exact location?

The following code:

```
pdf(file = "H:/temp/plots/demo.pdf", paper = 'letter', width=8.5, height = 11,
    pagecentre = FALSE)
par(mar = c(0,0,0,0))
par(mai = c(0,0,0,0))
par(mgp = c(0,0,0))
par(oma = c(0,0,0,0))
par(omi = c(0,0,0,0))
par(pin = c(8.5, 11))
par(xaxs = 'i')
par(yaxs = 'i')
par(xpd=TRUE)
par(pty='m')
plot(x=.25, y=10.75, type = 'p', ylab="", yaxt="n", bty="n",
     xlab="", xaxt = "n",
     xlim = c(0,8.5), ylim = c(0,11))
    lines(x=c(.25,.25), y=c(0,11))
    lines(x=c(0,8.5), y=c(10.75,10.75))
dev.off()
```

Produces a plot with a vertical line, a horizontal line, and point. The lines and the point should cross at .25 inches from the left and .75 inches from the top. It's close, but zooming in and the lines and point are off by fractions of an inch.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing is: don't use the `paper` argument. From `?pdf`:

> The paper argument sets the ‘⁠/MediaBox⁠’ entry in the file, which defaults to width by height. If it is set to something other than "special", a device region of the specified size is (by default) centred on the rectangle given by the paper size: if either width or height is less than 0.1 or too large to give a total margin of 0.5 inch, it is reset to the corresponding paper dimension minus 0.5.

In other words, if you specify `paper` there will always be inserted some margin that will mess things up.

Here is a minimal code that should be sufficient, no need to set up everything:

```r
pdf(file="demo.pdf", width=8.5, height=11)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0), xaxs='i', yaxs='i')
frame()
plot.window(xlim=c(0, 8.5), ylim=c(0, 11))
points(.25, 10.75)
lines(x=c(.25, .25), y=c(0, 11))
lines(x=c(0, 8.5), y=c(10.75, 10.75))
dev.off()
```

[image: pdf]